# MSAL login not working in production for node.js , Javascript application

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have used Msal.js for login to microsoft account inorder to call microsoft graph api.
On local everything is working fine but after deployment on production, login is happening but again a login popup is opening up , and my web application is not redirected to home page.

My redirect uri is : "http://localhost:8080/"

I am using node.js to create the localhost server.

My config.js file is  -

```
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: 'cbd4ec69-c747-4592-ae78-7d8d680d0428',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/'
    }
  };
  
  const msalRequest = {
    scopes: [
        'user.read',
      'Files.Read',
       'Files.Read.All',
        'Files.ReadWrite',
         'Files.ReadWrite.All'
    ]
  }
```

I need to deploy my application on prod, i have made the whole application and now only this thing is not working.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Do you change the configured redirectUri in prod?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround we can follow to resolve the above issue,

Make sure that the port you are using its been updated in `server.js` with your preferred port number in `redirect uri`.

We can follow the below given MS DOC and use the sample code.

The sample code will work like, ***When a user initially clicks the `Sign In` button, the signIn method invokes the `loginPopup` function to sign the user in. The `loginPopup` method prompts and validates the user's credentials by opening a pop-up window with the Microsoft identity platform endpoint. `Msal.js` starts the authorization code flow after a successful `sign-in`***.

For complete setup please refer this **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***Sign in users and call the Microsoft Graph API from a JavaScript***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code) .